# How to iterate class objects with arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, iteration, python-3.6

I'm trying to extract info from a csv file. Each line in the file contains several values for arguments that are used in a class. I want to take these values and give them to an object, but it needs to parse each line and create a new object with these argument values.

I would need each object to have a different name, e.g.: obj1 obj2 etc.

Here's how it would operate without iteration (only one object).

```
with open("file.csv") as csvfile:
            file = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
            for line in file:
                name = line["name"]
                cost = line["cost"]
                #one object manually entered
                obj = Class(name,cost)
            csvfile.close()
```

Comment: You can create dictionary of objects and get those objects by corresponding key in dictionary.

Comment: Or just a list.

Comment: Yes but it won't let you create a variable with a list or dictionary key. (t(0)=Class(parameter)) doesn't work, can't assign to function call).

Comment: I also require multiple parameters for each, not just a name with a key, so using t = {"x" : 0} wouldn't work because I need each to have multiple parameters and some of those parameters would be equal (can't do t = {"x": 0,"y":0})

Comment: @PatrickM "(t(0)=Class(parameter)) doesn't work" because that's not the correct syntax - it should be `t[0]=XXX` for a dict or `t.append(XXX)` for a list.

Answer (score 0):

You can create dictionary of objects and get those objects by corresponding key in dictionary.

```py
obj_dict = {}
with open("file.csv") as csvfile:
            file = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
            for idx, line in enumarate(file):
                name = line["name"]
                cost = line["cost"]
                #one object manually entered
                obj = Class(name,cost)
                obj_dict['obj{}'.format(idx+1)] = obj
            csvfile.close()

obj_dict['obj1'] # returns first object of type Class
```

**Also**:
Another way you can create variable with your name programatically , although it is not the recommended way for instantiating variables in code (for example your IDE might show error because it will think variable is not defined):

```py
_g = globals()

with open("file.csv") as csvfile:
      file = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
      for idx, line in enumarate(file):
           name = line["name"]
           cost = line["cost"]
           #one object manually entered
           obj = Class(name,cost)
           _g['obj{}'.format(idx+1)] = obj
           csvfile.close()
```

Comment: Please dont suggest doing ugly things with `globals` - we already see too much bad code.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I mentioned this in my answer.

Comment: the fact you mention it doesn't make it a lesser evil.

Answer (score 0):

Use a list, that's what they are for:

```
with open("file.csv") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    objects = [Class(row["name"], row["cost"]) for row in reader]   

# you don't need to close the file when using `with`

print(objects[0])
print(objects[1])
# etc
```